# Efficiently check the value of multiple variables against a list of values

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I want to create a variable that flags whether one or more of multiple variables has a particular value.

```
week  Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat
1     jon  jon   jon   jon    mary mary
2     jane jane  jane  jane   jane jane
3     mary mary  mary  mary   mary jane
```

I want to create a binary variable that flags for each week whether any day that week == "jon" or "mary" Is there a way to do this without creating a long ifelse statement that checks each variable individually?

```
week  Mon  Tues  Weds  Thurs  Fri  Sat  flag
1     jon  jon   jon   jon    mary mary 1
2     jane jane  jane  jane   jane jane 0
3     mary mary  mary  mary   mary jane 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base` solution:

```
df$flag <- +(colSums(apply(df[-1], 1, `%in%`, c("jon", "mary"))) > 0)
```

Or you can use `c_across()` from `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(c_across(-week) %in% c("jon", "mary"))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Both of them give:

```
#    week Mon   Tues  Weds  Thurs Fri   Sat    flag
# 1     1 jon   jon   jon   jon   mary  mary      1
# 2     2 jane  jane  jane  jane  jane  jane      0
# 3     3 mary  mary  mary  mary  mary  jane      1
```

---

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(week = 1:3, Mon = c("jon", "jane", "mary"), Tues = c("jon", 
"jane", "mary"), Weds = c("jon", "jane", "mary"), Thurs = c("jon", 
"jane", "mary"), Fri = c("mary", "jane", "mary"), Sat = c("mary", 
"jane", "jane")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I used colsums and it's perfect! Thank you

Comment: what if I only wanted to check for select variables (e.g., only Mon, Weds, Sat)? EDIT: nvm, it's clear how that would work from your dplyr example)

Comment: actually, when I try df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(flag = +any(c_across(Mon, Wed, Sat) %in% c("jon", "mary"))) %>%
  ungroup() I get an error. Is it not possible to do it this way?

Comment: @M1245689 you need to surround those variables into `c()`, i.e. `c_across(c(Mon, Weds, Sat))`. For the `base` solution, just replace `df[-1]` with `df[c("Mon", "Weds", "Sat")]` and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` :

```
df$flag <- +(rowSums(df[-1] == 'jon' | df[-1] == 'mary') > 0)

#  week  Mon Tues Weds Thurs  Fri  Sat flag
#1    1  jon  jon  jon   jon mary mary    1
#2    2 jane jane jane  jane jane jane    0
#3    3 mary mary mary  mary mary jane    1
```

If there are more values that you want to compare and cannot write each of them individually you can use any one of the following approach.

```
more_values <- c('jon', 'mary')
df$flag <- apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) as.integer(any(x %in% more_values)))
df$flag <- +as.integer(rowSums(sapply(df[-1], `%in%`, more_values)) > 0)
df$flag <- +(Reduce(`|`, lapply(df[-1], `%in%`, more_values)))
```